# dynamically connecting to multiple databases in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord, multiple-databases

my project require connecting to multiple databases within a rails project. The database information is not known in advance, so including the database information in `config/database.yml` is not an option. Here is my code to solve this :

```
mclass ConnectionManager
 @@connections_map = nil

 def self.create_connection(klass_name,database_params)
    @@connections_map[klass_name] = Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base) do |c|
      #c.abstract_class = true
      c.establish_connection(database_params)
    end
 end

 def self.connections
   @@connections_map = {} unless @@connections_map.present?
   mydata = MyModel.where(.....)
   mydata.each do |data|
     klass_name = data.name.camelcase
     create_connection(klass_name,data.database_params) unless @@connections_map[klass_name]
   end
   @@connections_map
 end
end
```

Now ideally I should be able to call `ConnectionManager.connections` which should return class objects with appropriate database connections.

But the problem is all the newly created class have the same connection information. The  last connection created is getting  overwritten to all the previous class objects.

What is wrong with this approach ?

Comment: I'm confused. You are creating new anonymous classes and calling establish_connection in them. Why not call establish_connection inside the model itself?

Comment: each mydata contains information about its database from which i can query more data. I am creating anonymous mydata classes with different database connections, so that i can query all of these database in parallel